# Setting struct fields from function

Tags: go

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, and I understand it's simple but I am new to go so bear with me.  I am trying to set the fields of a struct (`playersObject`) from two functions (`setCalculations` and `Calculations`), more specifically, I am passing in values of two arrays (`playerData` and `playerData2` from main to those functions, performing calculations in those functions, and want to return the values so that they can be set within the struct.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "bufio"
    "strconv"
)

type playersObject struct {

        firstname, lastname string
        batting_average, slugging_percentage, OBP, teamaverage float64
    }


func strToFloat(playerData []string, playerData2 []float64) []float64 {

        for _, i := range playerData[2:] {
            j, err := strconv.ParseFloat(i, 64)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            playerData2 = append(playerData2, j)
        }
        return playerData2
}

func (player *playersObject) setCalculations (playerData []string, playerData2 []float64)  {

    player.firstname = playerData[1]
    player.lastname = playerData[0]
    player.batting_average = (playerData2[2] + playerData2[3] + playerData2[4] + playerData2[5]) / (playerData2[1])
    player.slugging_percentage = ((playerData2[2]) + (playerData2[3]*2) + (playerData2[4]*3) + (playerData2[5]*4) )/(playerData2[1])
    player.OBP = (( playerData2[2] + playerData2[3] + playerData2[4] + playerData2[5] +playerData2[6] +playerData2[7])/ (playerData2[0]))

}

func (player *playersObject) Calculations () (string, string, float64, float64, float64, ) {

    return player.firstname, player.lastname, player.batting_average, player.slugging_percentage, player.OBP
}


func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter file name: ")
    fileName, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed opening file: %s", err)
        }
    fileName = strings.TrimSuffix(fileName, "\n")

    //fmt.Printf("%q\n", fileName)
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)
       scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
       scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
       var fileOfPlayers []string

       for scanner.Scan() {
           fileOfPlayers = append(fileOfPlayers, scanner.Text())
       }

       file.Close()


      // var total_Average_sum float64 = 0
       var countofplayers float64 = 0
       //var total_average float64 = 0
       for _, player := range fileOfPlayers {
        countofplayers ++
        playerData := strings.Split(player, " ")
        var playerData2 = []float64{}
        playerData2 = strToFloat(playerData, playerData2)

        player := playersObject{}
        player.setCalculations(playerData, playerData2)

        calcs := player.Calculations()

        fmt.Println(firstname, lastname, batting_average, slugging_percentage, OBP)

    }
}
```

I recieve the errors `multiple-value player.Calculations() in single-value contextand`  `undefined: firstname, lastname, batting_average, slugging_percentage, OBP`

I know this is very incorrect but again I am new to go and OOP. If this can be done in any simpler way I am open to it and appreciate all help and tips.  Thank you

Comment: Have you taken the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org)?

Comment: Please remain "new to OOP" as you continue to learn Go. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here, the error is thrown because `Calculations()` returns multiple values but you are trying to assign it to a single variable.

You need to change the `player.Calculations()` method invocation from

```
    calcs := player.Calculations()
```

to

```
firstname, lastname, batting_average, slugging_percentage, OBP := player.Calculations()
```

Having said that I would recommend you to read more about golang may be [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). You need to re-write the code in view of go best practises